# Как интегрировать JavaScript API в Home Assistant custom card?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-jsapi, импорт, cors

Пытаюсь интегрировать JS API в Custom Card Home Assistant - https://developers.home-assistant.io/docs/frontend/custom-ui/custom-card/.

В них импорт внешних js-файлов делается следующим образом -

```
import "https://unpkg.com/wired-card@0.8.1/wired-card.js?module";
```

Попробовал сделать то же самое с файлом `https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;apikey=1&module` - ругается на CORS.

Попробовал скачать файл, сохранить локально и импортировать как

```
import "/local/yandex-maps-api.js?module";
```

Так ошибки на импорт нет, но возникает ошибка

```
yandex-maps-api.js?module:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'performance')
    at ymapsInit (yandex-maps-api.js?module:1:84)
    at yandex-maps-api.js?module:1:28837
ymapsInit @ yandex-maps-api.js?module:1
(anonymous) @ yandex-maps-api.js?module:1
```

Что с этим делать?

Comment: Немного задача в целом не ясна. Интеграция платного API в индивидуальный интерфейс Home Assistant? А скачивать JS API Яндекса для использования вне сети они тоже запрещают. В чём тогда практический смысл задачи?

Comment: @YaCor', js api бесплатен, home assistant в сети

Comment: JS API бесплатен только при соблюдении условий использования. https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi-v2-1/doc/ru/v2-1/terms/index Вы интегрируете его в вашу личную закрытую извне систему (для всех других пользователей сети), а это платный сценарий использования, для которого нужна коммерческая лицензия.

Comment: @YaCor' почему вы решили, что к моему Home Assistant нет публичного доступа? 
Ну и, кажется, что мой вопрос не про лицензию был.

Comment: Вам следует попробовать JS API 3.0 Яндекса, поскольку import скорее похож на работу с React, нежели нативным JS (честно говорю, что про особенности Home Assistant не знаю). Но если такое размещение не будет передавать Яндексу referer публичной страницы, этого сделать не выйдет.